# Porting legacy Linux applications to FreeRTOS

Tags: linux, freertos

This might seem a bit vague but do let me know if some more info is required.
I've a got an application which runs on a custom microcontroller in Linux environment.
I wanna run the same application on iMXRT1050 microcontroller on FreeRTOS.
My Application has various modules attached to one Main.exe as static lib.

I have created C++ static library of all the module as a normal C++ project and linked to Main(which is a FreeRTOS project). I have resolved the build issue and it's compiling and building now but doesn't seem to work. I can't debug the application.Can someone help me with this? Is this the right way to approach?
I am currently using MCUXpresso IDE (but it's not manadatory. I can switch to watever is convinient)

Also if someone has worked in similar field (Porting a legacy linux app to freertos). please help.

Thanks

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a useful description of a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.